# How to generate task_id with year and sequence number in python that reset every year?

Tags: python, database

I want to generate task ids with the year and a sequence number that resets each year in python/django.

**Example:**

> 2019_01, 2019_02 .... 2020_01, 2020_02, 2020_03... etc..

How would I generate these values?

Comment: what do you want the sequence numbers to go up to? 12? How is this related to Django?

Comment: `[f'{year}_{month:02}' for year in range(2019, 2031) for month in range(1, 13)]`

Comment: This is not related to Django. Maybe if you want to perform this on your django application, but this is pure python.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 def gen_task_ids(start_year, end_year):
    task_ids = []
    for y in range(start_year, end_year+1):
         for m in range(1,13):
             month = "%.2d" % m
             task_ids.append(f'{y}_{month}')

    return task_ids

 gen_task_ids(2019, 2030)
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `range` to a `list` to iterate over it and `%` formatting should be avoided and you forgot the `f` in your f-string. You can do the `%.2d` logic in the f-string.